# Premature end of file. XML response

Tags: php, xml

I am getting a Premature end of file response to my XML request for following code.

Cant figure out where is the error.

```
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" ?>';
    $xml .= '<PickUpCityListRQ>';
    $xml .= '<Credentials username="'.$api->username.'" password="'.$api->password.'" remoteIp="'.$api->remoteIp.'" />';
    $xml .= '<Country>UK</Country>';
    $xml .= '</PickUpCityListRQ>';

    $url = 'https://secure.rentalcars.com/service/ServiceRequest.do?serverName=www.rentalcars.com&xml='.utf8_decode(trim($xml));
    $port = 443;

    $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $ch = curl_init();                              // initialize curl handle
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);            // set url to post to
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);    // Fail on errors

    if (ini_get('open_basedir') == '' && ini_get('safe_mode' == 'Off'))
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);// allow redirects
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    // return into a variable
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $port);          //Set the port number
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);          // times out after 15s
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '&xml='.$xml);     // add POST fields
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
    if ($port==443) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/xml; charset=UTF-8', 'Accept: application/xml; charset=UTF-8'));
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Have tried sending data in post fields as well but did not work.
Response:

```
<!DOCTYPE DefaultRS SYSTEM 'https://xml.rentalcars.com:443//tj.dtd'><DefaultRS>
<Error id="2">
<Message>Premature end of file.</Message>
</Error>
</DefaultRS>
```

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);`, in combination with the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` after that (_'resetting'_ it's content type) whould work.

Comment: Long shot, but you don't have any " in the username or password returned from the $api object, do you?

Comment: @JonRed: Yes I have checked $api object has relevant credentials and they are the correct ones.

Comment: @Wrikken: What to I need to reset the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER to? I have this at the moment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/xml; charset=UTF-8', 'Accept: application/xml; charset=UTF-8'));`

Comment: @Khawaib: seems OK, [this script here works on my server](http://pastebin.com/hmN2aABh), just remember to do it _after_ the `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);`

Comment: Manually building your XML? That's a fail in itself.

Comment: Hm, well, I get I SSL timeout if I test that particular service here... So other then: that's the proper way to send the XML I have no further tools to debug this (you might want to set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);`, but there it stops for me.

Comment: @Cole Johnson: I have tried to create XML both ways but same result. `    function createXmlDocument($api) {
        $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
        $root = $xmlDoc->appendChild($xmlDoc->createElement('PickUpCountryListRQ'));
...
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to url encode the xml data before you can use it as a query parameter. So the url assignment becomes:

```
$url = 'https://secure.rentalcars.com/service/ServiceRequest.do?
  serverName=www.rentalcars.com&xml='.urlencode(utf8_decode(trim($xml)));
```

Note, I've just wrapped that for readability - that should obviously be on one line.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot of variation I finally managed to make it work.

There were two things that were casuing problem.

utf8_decode should be utf8_encode

POSTFIELDS data is supposed to be an array

otherwise parser will throw Premature end of file or not send back anything.

Comment: You just failed to create valid XML because you do it yourself. You still will likely fail with what you have. Instead use a library to build the XML it will hint you encoding problems earlier then hitting the remote endpoint. So remember for everything you do now and in the future, say to yourself: I should not write it my own, I should find a library first that does it for me.

Comment: @hakre: There was no problem with XML, problem was with encoding and postfields data type.

Comment: are you sure you can differ and exclude that way? often that is the same. show the code so we can see and I will review again. promised.